# Starting using Google Sheets API cannot get configuration/token files

Tags: node.js, google-sheets-api

I need to get access at the sheets and I am following this guide to start to do that https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs

But the button that enables google APIs doesn't work, all names I put on the project return an error.

I went on the API console and created a new project but I do not know how to get credentials files (if they are needed) and then I must create an URL for the OAuth page?

Comment: May I ask you what exactly the error is? What do specify for configuiring the your OAuth client? Which king of applicaiton are you trying to set-up (how to get the right creadentials depends on this)?

Answer (score 1):

### How to get OAuth crendetials manually

- There different types of crendetials and the procedure to obtain them is slightly different depending on your situation.See [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2) for the different scenarios.
- In most cases (an exception is when using a [service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts)), **the first step**  is to set up an `OAuth consent screen`.
- The consent screen is the screen your users see when they are prompted to  agree to terms that are presented to them by your application
- To set up a OAuth consent screen, go after chosing a project from the GCP console on `APIs & services -> OAuth consent screen`
- You need to chose either your application is supposed to accessible only by domain **internal** users or also **external** (in the latter case you might need to submit your application for verification by Google, pontentially involving costs - depending on the scopes you use).
- You need to provide an application name that your users will see (the logo is optional)
- You need to specify which scopes your app will use
- You can specify other properties, e.g. the `Authorized domains` (this is usually your website from which the users will be redirected to the consent screen when performaing some kind of action)
- If you are not sure about the optional properties, leave them out for the start

---

- Once you set up the authentication screen, **the second step** is to go on `APIs & services -> Credentials`
- Read the [Authentication overview](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication) to decide which credentials you need
- For most applications you will want an `OAuth client ID`
- The diffrent Application types are described [here](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158849), to start with create a `Web Application`
- `Authorized JavaScript origins` and `Authorized redirect URIs` is basically your Webpage from which the users will be redirected to authenticate and to which they should be redirected after authentication.
- For local testing you do not need to specify those URLs
- Once you create the OAuth2 client successfully, you will obtain the `Client ID` and `Client Secret` - your crendetials to incorporate into your code when using Google APIs.
- If you click on the download button on the right side of your newly created credentials - it will generate a `json` file on your local machine from which the credentials will be read automatically if you follow the quickstart.
- Alternatively you can paste the credentials directly into your code - see [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client#google-apis-nodejs-client) for sample for different situations